# Getting error: "library not found for -lDoubleConversion" with React native 0.61.4 and xcode 12.1 while trying to product -> archive

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am getting error: "library not found for -lDoubleConversion" with **React native 0.61.4 and Xcode 12.1** The app runs perfectly fine on any other simulator device. But when I select generic device and do product->Archive I get this error. I have made sure that I open xcode through xcworkspace before build. I have already tried what similar posts on stackoverlflow suggested like deleting podlock deintegrating pod files and xcworkspace and regenerating them. I have also reinstalled node modules. I have also linked libDoubleConversion.a in build phases in xcode. I am literally struggling now as I have tried every solution. Please help. Thank you!
Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

$FirebaseSDKVersion = '6.13.0'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '5.8.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '5.8.0'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '5.8.0'

require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/cocoapods.rb'

target 'Messenger' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Messenger
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'React-ART', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ART'
  

  use_native_modules!
  use_unimodules!
end
pre_install do |installer|
  puts("Image fix for ios14: remove this when upgradeing to >= 0.63.3")
  find = "_currentFrame.CGImage;"
  replace = "_currentFrame.CGImage ;} else { [super displayLayer:layer];"
  op = `sed -ie "s/#{find}/#{replace}/" ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m`
  puts("Image fix for ios14 done")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the project in Xcode.
Just add the below line in '**library search path**' of the project.

```
"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/DoubleConversion"
```

And then clean build folder, And try rebuilding.
Then you have solved this problem.

Comment: have you executed pod install on the ios folder? @SiddharthSogani

Comment: yes i did pod install. Even deintegrated pod and podlock and installed again if you read my post.

Comment: This update to the library search path worked for me as well, at least for the DoubleConversion lib. Any idea why a search path of `"${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}"` set to `recursive` doesn't appear to work to find these libraries?