# How to build a working existing react native app on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

So I have an app that I have been working on for a far few months now. I developed it on Ubuntu and tested on my android phone and tablet. The app is setup using the basic react native library and I also added in expo later on for some little thing expo had that I needed. Let me know if you need more information about this.

The app is 'feature complete' and just needs to be play tested and released. So naturally I need to get it up and running on iOS. I am currently renting a mac that I can remote into (as I own no apple products).

It has been nearly a week now and I just cannot move past this error (see bottom) (or variations of what seem to be the same/similar errors). I can build a fresh app on this mac so everything is there to build react native apps. I have tried: Deleting pod and and running

```
pod install
```

running

```
pod deintegrate && pod install
```

deleting node modules and running

```
npm install
```

Initially I had an error complaining that some libraries were manually linked and this was bad so I unlinked them and now I get this error. I am opening that app using the workspace file when I run in xcode. I also get the error if running through command line i.e.

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

Using different simulators makes no difference...not sure if it is even getting that far in the build process for that to matter. I think this has something to do with the linking of RN libraries and this new auto link thing. Any thoughts? There are loads of posts with this error (or close to) that have all sorts of 'solutions', but none seem to make a difference. Overwhelmingly peoples solve this by pod install after deleting pod folder or running the `pod deintegrate` command. Looking at the error you can see that it prints out loads of libraries some of which I installed and others probably come with my 3rd party libraries, but some look like the core libraries and even low level looking ones that presumably RN is built on (but I honestly wouldn't know).

I was having issues before 'compiling' stuff and again I think it was to do with the linking.

Also, is there a 'react native' support service or something i.e. I pay some who knows apple and will just fix the damn thing for me

ERROR (scroll to the bottom for what is probably the important bit):

https://pastebin.com/HMdP4x3P

[EDIT]
I think this has something to do with my podfile: https://pastebin.com/5J7BbG2Q other pod files do not look like mine.

Comment: I don't use react-native (despise it), searching the error online, a bunch of people have the same issue and recommend a few steps that you don't mention above. This post talks about adding `DoubleConversion` manually in your podfile and running a special react setup script. Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239646/ld-library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion-react-native-0-59 . Someone else recommends manually adding it to the search paths: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64923949/getting-error-library-not-found-for-ldoubleconversion-with-react-native-0-61

Comment: This is my first experience developing apps and I have to say that of all the frameworks I have ever used for anything react native is awful. I will be glad when I am done with project because I am never using it again. No way is faster than developing on natively I just don't believe it.